# Post TypeScript Object without '_id' field?

Tags: mongodb, express, angular, typescript, mongoose

I use Express, Mongoose and Angular 2 (TypeScript) making an web app. Now I want to post a `MyClass` Instance without any `_id` field.

In mongoose we could use `_id` to do a lot of operations on mongoDB, so here is what I have done on the server side using `mongoose`

```
  router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Package.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
  });
});


/* GET /package/id */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Package.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* PUT /package/:id */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Package.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post, after) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

To contain the field `_id` I created a ts Class like this:

```
export class Package{


    constructor(
        public guid: string,
        ...
        [other fields]
        ...
        public _id: string
    ){}

}
```

Please note the `_id` at the end.

In my angular 2 service I am doing this to post the json object to server

```
//create new pakcage
    private post(pck: Package): Promise<Package> {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

        return this.http
            .post(this.packageUrl, JSON.stringify(pck), { headers: headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Then I received an error as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

In which it indicates that the object I post back got a empty `_id` field.

How do I post a ts class without the `_id` field or should I do it totally differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has given an answer I went to the internet and found a good example of how to implement a Angular2 -- Mongoose -- Express System.

https://github.com/moizKachwala/Angular2-express-mongoose-gulp-node-typescript

A very good example with the original Hero App from official tutorial. Although it is based on RC1 but it provides a good start point on how to do the RESTFUL Request properly.

Hope this would help someone who is looking for a similar answer.